# Can't resolve './lib' in '/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/simple-component-library/src'

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple component library using React. The file structure is as follows:

```
-src
--index.js
--lib
---TextInput.css
---TextInput.js
```

In my index.js file I'm referencing the lib folder like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { TextInput } from "./lib";
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Can't resolve './lib' in '/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/simple-component-library/src'
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh...okay, I realised what I didn't do! I didn't have an index.js file within my lib folder so I could export the component, like so:

```
import TextInput from "./TextInput";
export { TextInput };
```

So the new file structure will look like this:

```
-src
--index.js
--lib
---index.js
---TextInput.css
---TextInput.js
```